# Creating and Sorting a nested dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have two arrays:-

```
A=[a,d,b,c]
B=[e,g,f,h,k,l,m]
```

I want to create a nested dictionary by combing two arrays. I want to insert hello in a nested dictionary for each key pair. Expected result :

```
d=dict()
d={'a':{'e':'Hello','g':'Hello','f':'Hello','f':'Hello','h':'Hello','k':'Hello','l':'Hello','m':'Hello'},
    'b':{'e':'Hello','g':'Hello','f':'Hello','f':'Hello','h':'Hello','k':'Hello','l':'Hello','m':'Hello'},
c:{'e':'Hello','g':'Hello','f':'Hello','f':'Hello','h':'Hello','k':'Hello','l':'Hello','m':'Hello'} --------- }
```

My code :

```
for f in range(0,len(A)):
    d[f] = {}
    for i in range (0,len(B):
        if A[f] not in d:
            d[f]={}
        d[A[f]].update([B[i]]:'Hello')

print d
```

But what I am getting is the distorted dictionary. I was expecting results as I explained above but I am getting result a dictionary, not in proper order and sorting is messed up.

Please Help.

Comment: Welcome, you should read about python's dictionaries more. They are not sorted data structures. Lookup sorted dictionary

Comment: Dictionaries don't preserve insertion order until Python 3.7. In version 2.7+ you can use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class instead.

Answer (score 0):

OrderDict exists in python, but it does remember the order of keys insertion :

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {}
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
d['c'] = 3

for k,v in d.items():
  print(k,v)

#('a',1)
#('c',3)
#('b',2)

ord = {}
ord = {}
ord['a'] = 1
ord['b'] = 2
ord['c'] = 3

for k,v in ord.items():
  print(k,v)

#('a',1)
#('b',2)
#('c',3)
```

Official doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)